# Warning: subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql

When I run this query

```
SELECT a.sname,a.date,a.Roll_Number,b.branch,
                            COUNT(DISTINCT a.date) AS totaldays,
                            
                            (SELECT COUNT(a.attendance_status)
                            FROM attendance as a , branch as b  
                            WHERE a.attendance_status='Present' and b.id='".$_GET['id']."' and  a.branch=b.branch  GROUP BY a.sid )
                             as present_days
                             FROM attendance as a , branch as b  
                             WHERE
                              a.branch=b.branch
                            GROUP BY a.sname ";
```

it shows this error

> Warning: mysqli::query(): (21000/1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row

Help me to correct this query. Thank You in advance

Comment: `WHERE b.id='".$_GET['id']."'` <-- o.O. This is horrible - ready to get injected

Comment: Because you `GROUP BY`, your `COUNT()` can return more than one row. That is illegal for sub-queries, they can only return one row.

Comment: I need correct  query. Because I'm new to Mysql

Answer (score 1):

Looking to your query seems that you don't need the subquery for  present_days and avoing this subquery you shoudl avoid you error  ..

```
SELECT a.sname
  ,a.date,a.Roll_Number
  ,b.branch,
  COUNT(DISTINCT a.date) AS totaldays,
  COUNT(a.attendance_status) as present_days
  FROM attendance as a 
  INNER JOIN branch as b   ON a.attendance_status='Present' 
      and b.id='".$_GET['id']."' 
          and  a.branch=b.branch  
  GROUP BY a.sid
```

anyway you area risk for sqlinjection  .. you should not use php var in sql but use prepared statement and binding param ..